# I got the message error "Can't write image data to path (C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\webnsi\\public/assets/img/reward)" from laravel websi

Tags: php, laravel, web

I am using Laravel for webiste and i want to resize or customize the size that i want but I am not sure why I am getting this problem when everything else seems to be right. here is the code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Session;
use App;
use App\AllData;
use App\AwardCertification;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Banner;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
....
public function store(Request $request){
        $award = new AwardCertification;
        $kd = Str::random(15);

        $award->name = $request->name;

        // store image
        if($request->hasFile('file')){
            $image = $request->file('file');
            $img = Image::make($image);
            $img->resize(500, 500, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
            $img->save(public_path().'/assets/img/reward', $kd . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension());
            $award->image = $kd . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
        }

        // save
        if($award->save()) {
            return $this->response(0, 'Data Created Successfull');
        } else {
            return $this->response(1, 'Failed Created Data');
        }
    }
```

i want to upload file and customize the size and save to '/assets/img/reward'

Answer (score 0):

If `reward` is your folder, then you should add `/` to the end

```
$img->save(public_path().'/assets/img/reward/' . $kd . "." . $image->getClientOriginalExtension());
                                           ^^^
```

and make sure the directory exists and permission is set

```
mkdir(public_path().'/assets/img/reward', 0777, true);
```

Comment: still not working on me, the permission after or before resize statement?